# Page redirects does not keep the query string part of the URL after sitefinity version 8.2 migration? [asp.net/C#]

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity-8

It seems that when a page has URLs, and when a redirect occurs **query string portion gets discarded**.

Just wondering if anybody else encountered this issue. Or possibly my page settings are not set correctly.

This is happening on a page that I migrated from sitefinity version 4.2 to 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been resolved in later versions of Sitefinity, v.11+

https://feedback.progress.com/Project/153/feedback/Details/255376-multiple-page-url-lost-query-string-after-redirecting-to-the-default-url